# Create array of all ExpressionTree/Func-parameters

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees

Output of the following program is:

First: System.String. Second: System.String.

The expected result is:
First: hello1. Second: hello2.

If i hardcode the index to 1 or 2 in 
Expression.Assign(resultArrayAccessor, parameters[0]) it works, but i need to have the index following the variable i.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var type = typeof(Func<string, string, object>);
        var del = GenerateFunc<Func<string, string, object>>(type);
        del("hello1", "hello2");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static T GenerateFunc<T>(Type type)
    {
        var i = Expression.Parameter(typeof (int), "i");

        var x = type.GetMethod("Invoke");
        var target = typeof (Program).GetMethod("Target");

        var resultArray = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "result");
        var parameterArray = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ParameterExpression[]), "parameters");

        var resultArrayAccessor = Expression.ArrayAccess(resultArray, i);
        var parameterArrayAccessor = Expression.ArrayAccess(parameterArray, i);

        var label = Expression.Label();

        var parameters = x.GetParameters().Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, p.ParameterType.ToString())).ToArray();

        var block = Expression.Block(x.ReturnType,
            new[] { resultArray, i, parameterArray },
            Expression.Assign(resultArray, Expression.Constant(new object[parameters.Length])),
            Expression.Assign(parameterArray, Expression.Constant(parameters)),
            Expression.Loop(
                Expression.Block(
                    Expression.IfThenElse(
                        Expression.LessThan(i, Expression.Constant(parameters.Length)),
                            Expression.Block(
                                Expression.Assign(resultArrayAccessor, parameterArrayAccessor),
                                Expression.PostIncrementAssign(i)
                            ),
                        Expression.Break(label)
                    )
                ),
                label
            ),

            Expression.Call(target, resultArray)
        );


        return Expression.Lambda<T>(block, parameters).Compile();
    }

    public static object Target(object[] test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First: " + test[0] + ". Second: " + test[1] + ".");
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what are you actually trying to do? Just knowing the actual and expected results is not enough. Also, can't you simplify your code so that it still shows the problem, but with less code?

Comment: Im building my own IoC container (dont want any external dependencies) for an open source projects im working on. So i want to be able to inject a Func<param1, param2, newObject> newObjectFactory into the constructor. I want this to be generic, i want to create an object[] of all the parameters passed in the func because then the IoC container can fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out, much easier syntax aswell as actually working ;)

```
public static T GenerateFunc<T>(Type type)
{
    var target = typeof (Program).GetMethod("Target");

    var invokeMethod = type.GetMethod("Invoke");
    var parameters = invokeMethod
      .GetParameters()
      .Select(pi => Expression.Parameter(pi.ParameterType, pi.Name))
      .ToList();

    var parametersExpression = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), parameters);
    var body = Expression.Call(target, parametersExpression);
    return Expression.Lambda<T>(body, parameters).Compile();
}
```